# How do I create a dynamic list in template metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, list, templates, variadic-templates

I've been trying template metaprogramming and have had some trouble making a dynamic list. I've tried

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<int I>
struct Int {

};
template<class _Value, class ..._Others>
struct List {
    typedef _Value Value;
    typedef List<_Others...> Next;
};
template<class _Value>
struct List<_Value, void> {
    typedef _Value Value;
    typedef void Next;
};

template<class _List>
void PrintList() {
    std::cout << typename _List::Value::I << "\n";
    PrintList<typename _List::Next>();
};
template<>
void PrintList<void>() {};

int main() {
    PrintList<List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>>>();
}
```

But I get 2 compile errors that I can't figure out. The first is `expected '(' before '<<' token` on `std::cout << typename _List::Value::I << "\n";`. I can't figure out how to print out the int value (I've also tried `(typename _List::Value)::I`).

The second error is that I have the wrong number of template arguments at `typedef List<_Others...> Next;`. Shouldn't the first argument be capped into `Value`, and the rest `Others`?

Comment: There are two separate compilation errors here, with completely different root causes that have nothing to do with each other, and would have separate answers. One question per stackoverflow.com question, please. Can you limit your question to exactly one question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access template parameters using `::` syntax. The usual convention is to add `type` `using` for types and `value` `constexpr static` member for values.

```cpp
template<int I>
struct Int {
   constexpr static auto value=I;
};
```

Then use
`std::cout << _List::Value::value << "\n";`. It is not a type, so putting `typename` there was also incorrect.

The second error is because you defined `List` having at least one argument, yet you recurse into `List<_Others...>` which is empty at the end. Even though you wanted to fix it with `void`, you forgot to add it to the list, try `PrintList<List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>,void>>();`

But having a sentinel value is not necessary, see this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
template<int I>
struct Int {
    static constexpr auto value=I;
};
//Define List as naturally having any number of arguments, even zero.
template<class...Ts>
struct List{};

//Non-empty specialization.
template<class Head, class...Tail>
struct List<Head,Tail...>{
    using head = Head;
    using tail = List<Tail...>;
};

template<class _List>
void PrintList() {
    std::cout <<  _List::head::value << "\n";
    PrintList<typename _List::tail>();
};
//Printing empty list.
template<>
void PrintList<List<>>() {};

int main() {
    PrintList<List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>>>();
}
```

It is better to use `using` in C++, they are more readeable and can be templated.

In C++17 you can use fold expressions:

```cpp
template<typename...Elements>
void fold_print(List<Elements...>){
    ((std::cout<<Elements::value<<'\n'),...);
}
int main() {
    fold_print(List<Int<1>, Int<2>, Int<3>>{});
}
```

But functions can unpack only their arguments, so the syntax is slighlty different. Or it would require one more `struct` wrapper that unpacks them.